# NavAgent Destination Switching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a NavAgent that is supposed to randomly run from one target location to the next. Here is my current code.

```
public Transform target1;
public Transform target2;
NavMeshAgent agent;
Vector3 destinationLoc;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    destinationLoc = target1.position;
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    agent.SetDestination (destinationLoc);
    Debug.Log (agent.remainingDistance);
    if (agent.remainingDistance <= 1.0) {
        Debug.Log ("It gets here.");
        if (Random.Range(1,3) == 1) {
            destinationLoc = target1.position;
            Debug.Log ("Changed to 1.");
        } else {
            destinationLoc = target2.position;
            Debug.Log("Changed to 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it only switches between two locations but it will eventually be more. Any thoughts on why this code is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be doing an overkill on setting the destination.  I would set it up once in the Start() and again only once it has reached its destination.  As for the Random.Range(1,3), may be a complete coincidence.  You are getting an integer of 3 possibilities and it is returning 1.  Try putting into a var, showing the log and adjust from there.  Try expanding the range to 30 (for testing)

```
void Start () {
    destinationLoc = target1.position;
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
    agent.SetDestination (destinationLoc);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Debug.Log (agent.remainingDistance);
    if (agent.remainingDistance <= 1.0) {
        Debug.Log ("It gets here.");
        int rr = Random.Range(1,30);
        Debug.Log( "Random value: " + rr );

        if (rr == 1) {
            destinationLoc = target1.position;
            Debug.Log ("Changed to 1.");
        } else {
            destinationLoc = target2.position;
            Debug.Log("Changed to 2");
        }

        // Set destination AFTER it has been changed
        agent.SetDestination (destinationLoc);

    }
}
```

Additionally, you might get a better and faster response by going to the sister site of

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfect. To explain to others why this solution worked and mine didn't: You have to put the original setDestination in the start and only change it when you need to. You set the destination after everything else has been done.